# Why is passing window.location.hostname to this conditional statement causing a Cross Origin Error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx

Hi I am trying to pass a list of products to this render method based on an if statement for the domain hostname being matching (later on it would be fetched), I did have it once before but I changed the code refactoring for hooks. But I wanted to end the night with the old base and as I tried to convert it back it wouldnt work. Here is the code thanks for the help. I do not have any error logs

```
export default class Products extends Component {
  render() {
    if(window.location.host !== "1jvrt.csb.app") {
      const bikes = [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Adult Male Bike",
          price: 20.5,
          image: "http://via.placeholder.com/250x250?text=Adult%20Male%20Bike",
          product_type: "bike"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Adult Female Bike",
          price: 20.5,
          image: "http://via.placeholder.com/250x250?text=Adult%20Female%20Bike",
          product_type: "bike"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Kids Unisex Bike",
          price: 12.75,
          image: "http://via.placeholder.com/250x250?text=Kids%20Unisex%20Bike",
          product_type: "bike"
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: "Adult Unisex Helmet",
          price: 4.0,
          image:
            "http://via.placeholder.com/250x250?text=Adult%20Unisex%20Helmet",
          product_type: "accessory"
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          name: "Kids Unisex Helmet",
          price: 3.5,
          image: "http://via.placeholder.com/250x250?text=Kids%20Unisex%20Helmet",
          product_type: "accessory"
        },
        {
          id: 6,
          name: "Insurance",
          price: 9.99,
          image: "http://via.placeholder.com/250x250?text=Insurance",
          product_type: "addon"
        }
      ];
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>
          <div className="contrainer">
            <div className="row">
              {bikes.map(bike => (
                <div className="col-md-4">
                  <div className="card m-2">
                    <img
                      className="card-img-top"
                      src={bike.image}
                      alt="aaaaaaaa"
                    />
                    <div classme="card-body">
                      <h4 className="card-title">{bike.name}</h4>
                      <p className="card-text">words</p>
                      <button className="btn btn-outline-primary">
                        Buy Now
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        ); } return (
        <div>
          Tell The store owner you want to order online and pick up in store
          with instaEstore!
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Note if I pass the const of bikes outside it works fine

Comment: `I do not have any error logs` - so where is the "cross origin error" if there are no errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues with your code posted -

1) Your JSX is not right, check for `; } return (` in JSX.

2) You are declaring bikes `const` in if statement. Instead you can define `bikes` with an empty array and then add value to it inside if.

Working Code - https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-meitner-dof9y

Comment: Thanks, usually I would have ran it through a linter. It was so late my mistake.